# How to create a COM object in F#

Tags: f#, com

I need IMessage Interface. In C# I could write

```
CDO.Message oMsg = new CDO.Message(); // ok
```

but when I try to do this in F#

```
let oMsg = new CDO.Message()
```

I get an error message:

> 'new' cannot be used on interface types. Consider using an object expression '{ new ... with ... }' instead.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145234/how-to-convert-c-sharp-code-that-uses-shell-com-to-f/37150493#37150493

Comment: Of interest: [COM Type Provider for F#](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.ComProvider/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the version that has the "Class" added to the interface name:

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
[<STAThread>]
let main argv = 
    let oMsg =  new CDO.MessageClass()  
    oMsg.Subject <- "Hello World" 
    Console.WriteLine(oMsg.Subject)
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Note: I also explicitly had to add a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library` to the project to make the object instantiation work.

In case you want to use the specific interface and not the Co-Class (as proposed by Hans Passant), use this version that casts the created Co-Class to the interface, thereby returning a pointer to the actual interface.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
[<STAThread>]
let main argv = 
    let oMsg =  upcast new CDO.MessageClass()  : CDO.IMessage
    oMsg.Subject <- "Hello World" 
    Console.WriteLine(oMsg.Subject)
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do glance at the linked duplicate to see why type inference is not a great idea.

Comment: Added variant that uses the interface and not the co-class to access further members after creation