# How ensure only to use correct COM types in code?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

When I add a COM reference I get an automatically generated interop. In this example I added a reference to MSHTML.

I had the problem with the following code:

```cs
bool isHtmlFrameElement = activeElement is HTMLFrameElement;
```

This type test works on target systems that have a proper mshtml interop in the GAC. But on other systems this expression [always became true even if it was not an HTMLFrameElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035209/why-can-i-cast-a-com-object-to-a-wrong-interface). Correct check would be the following.

```cs
bool isHtmlFrameElement = activeElement is IHTMLFrameElement;
```

How can I ensure to avoid using *invalid* types during development?

My first thoughts on this:

- Post-process the generated interops to make all *meta* types internal
- Post-process consuming assemblies during build and raise build errors

Comment: Using post processing, you can make sure the used type has no CoClassAttribute defined https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.coclassattribute

Comment: But I would also have to check to avoid the type mentioned in the _CoClassAttribute_ (HTMLFrameElementClass).  And there are also the Disp* types that also wouldn't work. The DispHTMLFrameElement could be excluded because it has an [_InterfaceTypeAttribute_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.interfacetypeattribute?view=net-6.0) with value 2?

Comment: You can't enforce every possible error. I must also be an 'interface', not a 'class'. The last test or warning would be to check the name starts with an uppercase i (for Interface). Although it's not 100% sure, most if not all Microsoft interface definitions start with an I

Comment: Probably the [_TypeLibTypeAttribute_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.typelibtypeattribute?view=net-6.0) should also be considered. I guess these flags provide the required information.